# DOM created screenshots as PNG files

Tags: javascript, php, html2canvas

I am using `html2canvas.js` to create a screenshot of a webpage. The only thing is that I don't know how to transfer this data to an image file format so that I can save it and link it in the database.

This is my current code:

```html
<script language="Javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas2) {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 240, 180);
                $.post(
                    "' . self::get_link('save_screenshots') . '",
                    "user_id=' . module_security::get_loggedin_id() .
                    '&screenshot=" + encodeURI(canvas2.toDataURL())
                );
                document.body.appendChild(canvas2)
            }
        })
    }, 1*60*1000);
</script>
```

Comment: After the toDataURl("image/png") , you will get a base64 format data. Do you mean how to handle this base64 data in server side?

Comment: Yes, the origional idea was to run the base64 data through a PHP script and upload it to a database.

Comment: but if that isn't possible I would like to save the data as a .png file and store it in the images directory with a link to the database.

Comment: That's possible but I don't think store the image data into database is kind of best pratical. So I suggest to store it into images directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
<?php
    // requires php5
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'your/images/directory/');
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $img_file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($img_file, $data);
    if($img_file){
        // store the link to database
    } else{
       //return error msg
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should let jQuery handle the request encoding for you:

```
$.post(url, {
    user_id: 123,
    screenshot: canvas2.toDataURL()
}, function() {
    // success
    document.body.appendChild(canvas2);
});
```

Then, you decode it like so on the server side:

```
$data = base64_decode(substr(
    $_POST['screenshot'], 
    strpos($_POST['screenshot'], ',') + 1
));
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your post. Could you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: @jfh6 Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @jfh6 Well, the value of `canvas2.toDataURL()` gets encoded by jQuery to make sure the `+` doesn't accidentally gets turned into spaces ... it uses `encodeURIComponent()` internally ... the request body would look like "user_id=123&screenshot=data%3Aimage/png%3Bbase64%2C<data>".

Comment: Oh okay, i didn't know that jquery did that internally. Thanks for the information. I can't vote up on your post because my reputation is low on stack overflow, or I would, thanks for this helpful tip.